# "I need to work on..." for a general sentence

Tags: traducción

This is for a handout to parents of a special education class.  They speak no English, and the teacher speaks no Spanish. Thus general partial stock phrases are provided on the sheet and she translates only the activity needed.

In English the sheet would say:

> I need to work on *_*_.

In Spanish, would it work to say:

> Necesito trabajar en *_*_.

Keep in mind that it must be neutral and work for a variety of activities.  Is the way 'en' refer to an activity equivalent to the English 'on'?  Would another verb be better suited, such as 'practicar'?

Comment: It's ok for me. "Practicar" is a litle less general ("to practice").

Comment: Interesting. I always considered *en* to be like *in*. But the only other similar word I can think of would be *sobre*. Not a native Spanish speaker though, so I'm interested to see what others say about this!

Comment: @WendiKidd "en" can mean "in" or "on" depending on context (in fact this is often a point of confusion for native Spanish speakers speaking English). For example, "ponlo en la mesa" = "put it **on** the table". You wouldn't say "ponlo sobre la mesa" for something like a bowl or plate.

Comment: @Meep it would help if you gave a few examples of the activities.

Comment: "...to work on..." could mean to improve or to practice so it may be better to use the appropriate one.

Comment: I suggest that "to work on" is a separate idea from the "to work".  So "on" shouldn't be translated separately.  I would use "practicar" is the object is a language, or a skill where practice makes perfect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an answer from a Spaniard from Spain, which doesn't mean mine is better than the rest. However, I can tell from my experience that...

When you want to use the verb "trabajar" meaning "to improve" or "to practice" you can use it with "en", "sobre" and "con". For instance, "necesito trabajar en ello" = "necesito trabajar sobre ello" = "necesito trabajar con ello". The word "ello" could be substituted by what I need to improve or practice. It's very common to get rid of all these propositions when the object is clearly identified. For instance, I would say "necesito trabajar el temario para el próximo examen" rather than "necesito trabajar en/sobre/con el temario para el próximo examen".

Comment: Thanks, the possibility of dropping the proposition entirely does simplify it.

Answer (score 3):

I'll show a few examples containing phrases with similar meaning to "I need to work on__".
None of the examples directly translate the word **work**.
It is implicit in some way. I boldfaced the cases:

**Tengo que mejorar** mis calificaciones.
**Tengo que practicar más** mi español.
**Necesito esforzarme más en** la dieta que estoy haciendo.
**Debo tomarme más en serio** las normas de etiqueta.
**Debo prestar más atención a** los reclamos de mi esposa.

Comment: Thank you.  To go with Arturo's answer, a good general translation might be:

"Tengo que practicar..."

With no need for a proposition?

Comment: @Meep "Tengo que practicar mi español.": this is OK too. But it has less emphasis, I think. Anyway, I feel that is a good translation, also. (I am a native speaker spanish, so I can tell you what sounds good to me, or if the sense of the sentence seems to be mantained when I am hearing it).

Comment: Thanks!  I think this will be a good solution then for a general fill in the blank format for a variety of actions then.